# Tensorflow Object Detection Killed before starting

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I am running docker image tensorflow:1.1.0. I have added the tensorflow object detection api github by cloning it locally and giving my docker a connection to the folder. I am trying to recreate their pet example.

I believe I have all code and code in the right places. However, when I try to retrain, tensorflow kills itself before starting to train, but does not give any issues or errors.

```
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
Killed
```

I imagine I have something out or oder, but without any errors or output I don't know where to look!

I am following the guide here to run things locally: [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md). The pet data was obtained from the same GitHub: [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/preparing_inputs.md). I got my model configuration from the same GitHub as well. [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)

I choose inception_v2.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your set up? What is the `docker run` command (or equivalent) that you are running? can you provide a link to this "pet example"?

Comment: I used this code to start my docker:
    docker run -it --rm --name bob -p 1000:8888 -v /Users/.../tensorflow/models:/notebooks tensorflow/tensorflow:1.1.0

Where tensorflow/models contains my local copy of the models GitHub.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but my program got a little bit further.
`INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 0.
INFO:tensorflow:global step 1: loss = 0.6946 (6.841 sec/step)
`

Comment: Update, I ran this with optimizations, hoping that it would have time to process, with no luck.

Comment: Maybe this can help you...[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150773/tensorflow-object-detection-training-killed-resource-starvation/46945403#46945403)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow Object Detection Training Killed, Resource starvation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150773/tensorflow-object-detection-training-killed-resource-starvation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now realize that I was simply running out of memory as soon as I started. When I switched to `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17` and changed `batch_size = 1`, it all worked.

This still doesn't entirely fix my problem though. I'll have to figure out how to provide more memory for the call.