# Retrain an object detection model - Out of memory (OOM) Killer - Google coral

Tags: tensorflow, google-coral

I was trying to **Retrain an object detection model for Google coral accelerator** as per the below link

https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/retrain-detection/#prerequisites

The host system is based on Linux Mint with docker environment

- CPU :  Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz
- Graphics:  Card:   Intel HD Graphics 5500
- OS : Linux Mint 19 Tara
- Memory Size: 8G

But after Starting the training job

root@beaa5d65a1d5:/tensorflow/models/research# ./retrain_detection_model.sh --num_training_steps ${NUM_TRAINING_STEPS} --num_eval_steps ${NUM_EVAL_STEPS}

The process is killed by OOM killer

> *./retrain_detection_model.sh: line 45:    86 Killed*
>   python object_detection/model_main.py
>   --pipeline_config_path="${CKPT_DIR}/pipeline.config" --model_dir="${TRAIN_DIR}" --num_train_steps="${num_training_steps}" --num_eval_steps="${num_eval_steps}"

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: is there a `--batch_size` option? Decreasing the batch_size reaquires less memory but slows down training. Do you get an OOM with `--batch_size=1`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any --batch_size argument in ./retrain_detection_model.sh. I am very new to this, so not sure this available for modification in some other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an out of memory issue due to HW limitation. 2 things you can do is to either add more RAM or Swapspace (using storage as RAM). Although going with the later will be very slow.

Comment: Thank you Nam Vu, 
I saw below solution from another stackoverflow , but I dont know how to apply in the current context, where can I edit, any help

"Actually,the memory full use is caused by the data_augmentation_options ssd_random_crop, so you can remove this option and set the batch size to 8 or smaller ie,2,4. When I set batch size to 1,I also met some problems cause by the nan loss.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150773/tensorflow-object-detection-training-killed-resource-starvation

Comment: Hi, I answered via emails but a short summary here for other to reference: If you want to change any of the parameters, you have to log into the docker image and change those parameters in the pipeline.config file. This file should be /tensorflow/models/research/configs directory, named after the model you chose. Then you can try changing the "batch_size" parameter to see if that helps.
Changing these parameters means that you'll want to train the model in a more sequential rather than parallel way.

Comment: Thank you Nam Vu, Appreciate your effort.

Comment: Thank you Nam Vu, Appreciate your effort.
One suggestion: I will be useful for newbies if you can update Google coral Support documentation with appropriate host machine specifications

Comment: Hi, will do, we are actually going through a lot of changes in our documentation right now. I'll add this to the list.

Comment: Can I do "Retrain an object detection model for coral" using google colab?

Comment: Will definitely do, although we don;t have a commited time frame for this yet!